# Format Data to plot on Line chart using High charts

Tags: node.js, typescript, highcharts, momentjs, linechart

Below is the data in JSON format that I have . Values will be summed
up for each month and grouped by year to get the right format to plot line charts.

```
const listItems = [{
        "id": 1,
        "total": 21.15,
        "dat": "2017-10-21T08:32:36.000Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "total": 22,
        "dat": "2018-04-24T13:46:16.000Z"
      },{
        "id": 3,
        "total": 11,
        "dat": "2017-11-24T13:46:16.000Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "total": 12,
        "dat": "2018-04-02T09:15:35.000Z",
      }
    ]
```

I want convert it into below format to plot it on the Line chart. It is comparison of two years 2017 and 2018 for each month .

```
var xAxis = {
      categories: [
        "Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"
      ]
    };
    var series = [
      {
        name: "2017",
        data: [
          7.0,6.9,9.5,14.5,18.2,21.5,25.2,26.5,23.3,18.3,13.9,9.6
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "2018",
        data: [-0.2, 0.8,5.7,11.3,17.0,22.0,24.8,24.1,20.1,14.1,8.6,2.5
        ]
      }
    ];
```

Comment: Could you please give us more information what do you want to achieve here? Thank you!

Comment: Hi @MOFD, Could you describe your problem more precisely? How exactly do you want to transform the values?